When we have the highest order of convergence of this iterative method
Problem:
Find the values of $p, q, r$ in the following iteration formula to ensure that the iterative method converges to $\sqrt{c}$ and achieves the highest order of convergence:
$$x_{k+1} = p x_k + \frac{q c}{x_k} + \frac{r c^2}{x_k^3}.$$
My try:
Assume $c>0$
Define
$$
f(x) = p x + \frac{q c}{x} + \frac{r c^2}{x^3}.
$$
Then we have
$$
f'(x) = p - \frac{q c}{x^2} - \frac{3 r c^2}{x^4}
$$
and
$$
f''(x) = \frac{2 q c}{x^3} + \frac{12 r c^2}{x^5}.
$$
Next, we use Taylor expansion around $x=\sqrt{ c }$:
$$
x_{k+1} = f(\sqrt{c}) + f'(\sqrt{c}) (x_k - \sqrt{c}) + \frac{f''(\sqrt{c})}{2} (x_k - \sqrt{c})^2 + o((x_k - \sqrt{c})^2).
$$
Since this method converges to $\sqrt{ c }$, we have
$$
f(\sqrt{c}) = \sqrt{c}.
$$
This leads to the equation
\begin{equation}
p + q + r = 1 \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
and
$$
x_{k+1}-\sqrt{ c }=f'(\sqrt{ c })(x_{k}-\sqrt{ c })+\frac{f''(\sqrt{ c })}{2}(x-\sqrt{ c })+o((x_{k}-\sqrt{ c })^2).
$$
To achieve the highest order of convergence, we require:
$$
\begin{align}
f'(\sqrt{ c }) = 0, \\
f''(\sqrt{ c })= 0. \label{eq:2}
\end{align}
$$
This leads to the equations:
$$
\begin{align}
p - q-3r = 0, \\
q+ 6r = 0.
\end{align}
$$
Now we can get
$$
p = \frac{3}{8}, 
q=\frac{3}{4}, 
r= -\frac{1}{8}.
$$

I did not check the final calculations, but your approach is correct.
For an alternative path, one could also start with $$\sqrt{c}=x_k\sqrt{\frac{c}{x_k^2}}=x_k\sqrt{1-a}=x_k\left(1-\frac a2-\frac{a^2}8\pm ...\right)$$ with $a=1-\frac{c}{x_k^2}$ a small residual. The binomial series $(1+a)^r=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{r}{k}a^k$ is used to expand the square root.
Now expand the approximation
$$
x_{k+1}=x_k\left(1-\frac12\left(1-\frac{c}{x_k^2}\right)-\frac18\left(1-\frac{c}{x_k^2}\right)^2\right)
$$
and you should get the same formula.
